# 'Select Listing Name to Scan' is empty in the Partner Security Portal

Tags: apex, package, security-review, partner-communities, 2gp

As mentioned by @phil in [Sending review to the checkmarx where multiple developments are included](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398971/sending-review-to-the-checkmarx-where-multiple-developments-are-included/398978#398978) I have gone to partner security portal.

Though the packages are being displayed in the partner community, the details in my partner security portal is empty and not showing any data.

[image: My partner community]

And below is the pic of my partner security portal:

[image: Partner security portal]

What steps should I have to do now so that I can run the scan for the packages?

Comment: Have you actually created an App Exchange listing for your package (this can be private)? Have you followed the instructions in the [ISVforce guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_how_it_works.htm)?

Comment: The ISVforce guide has a lot of information. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish.htm) is a higher-level page explaining the sequence you need to go through, with links to the detail. Security review is just one step on this journey.